# Saber listado de options de un input con jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo el siguiente código, que debería de traer a la variable `mke` la cantidad de opciones dentro de un input tipo select.
Hay otro subinput que se muestra si la cantidad de opciones del primer input es > que 1, y si es 1, ocultarlo

El problema es que en la consola a veces `mke` es 1, a veces muestra la cantidad correcta, a veces no....

**EL SEGUNDO SELECT SE RELLENA DE OPCIONES DEPENDIENDO DEL PRIMERO**

```js
$(function () {
        $("#COMMISSION_MODALIDAD_PRODUCTO").change(function () {
            var mke = $("#COMMISSION_SUBMODALIDAD_PRODUCTO").children('option').length;
            $("#COMMISSION_SUBMODALIDAD_PRODUCTO").hide();
            if (mke > 1) {
                $("#COMMISSION_SUBMODALIDAD_PRODUCTO").show();
            }
            console.log(mke);
        });
        $("#COMMISSION_MODALIDAD_PRODUCTO").trigger("change");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="COMMISSION_MODALIDAD_PRODUCTO">
  <option value="">Seleccione...</option>
  <option value="">asdf</option>
  <option value="">qwe</option>
  <option value="">rewq</option>
</select>
<select id="COMMISSION_SUBMODALIDAD_PRODUCTO">
  <option value="">Seleccione...</option>
  <option value="">asdf</option>
  <option value="">qwe</option>
  <option value="">rewq</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Contar con el **HTML** pertinente para poder componer un ejemplo mínimo y verificable estaría bien como punto de partida.

Comment: Entendí que la variable `mke` quieres que tenga el número de `<option>` del primer `<select>`, sin embargo estás capturando en ella el número de `<option>` del segundo `<select>`. ¿Es esto lo que quieres?

Comment: Al contrario, quiero obtener el numero de options del segundo select al hacer cambios en el primero

Comment: Entonces redacta de nuevo la pregunta porque creo que no se entiende muy bien lo que quieres hacer. "Hay otro subinput que se muestra si la cantidad de opciones del primer input es > que 1, y si es 1, ocultarlo" eso da a entender lo contrario.

Answer (score 0):

prueba esto:

```
var mke = $( "#COMMISSION_SUBMODALIDAD_PRODUCTO option").length
```

en jquery no hace falta hacer `.children`.